# Improve workout endurance and results by adding nutrition supplements?

Tags: diet, nutrition, performance

I work out every other day, and do cardio in between, with 1 or 2 days rest in a week.

My work out program:

```
1.5 km treadmill 
Row machine: 2x10 
Chest machine: 2x10 
Leg Press: 2x10 
Back Extension: 2x10 
Torso Extension: 2x10 
TRX Rowing: 3x10
TRX Push up: 3x10
Russian Twist: 3x10
Leg lift: 3x10
Pull ups (As many as I can)
Dips (As many as I can)
```

My average daily diet consists of 3 meals per day:

**Morning**: 200ml milk, scrambled egg, and a banana

**Lunch**: Chicken breast / Fish + boiled vegetables such as broccoli, cauliflower, or potatoes

**Afternoon Snack**: Apple

**Dinner**: 2 whole eggs, vegetables, and cheese

**Snack**: Nuts

My question is whether adding a **protein shake to my nutrition**, would be of any benefit in my muscle building.

I know that eating more would produce the same effect, but I do not wish to add more food in my diet. I must mention that I am 21 years old, 188 cm and 76 kg, and my aim is to get "toned". Since many people have different definitions of toned, mine is having low body fat and well-defined muscles.

Comment: You don't seem to eat a lot of carbs, do you do that deliberately? And also, do you know how many grams of protein you are getting in a day right now? Whether or not you should add a protein shake will depend heavily on that. But I'd say if you want to add anything I think you need some carbs.

Comment: @MJB I am trying to avoid carbs in order to remove the belly fat. Regarding the proteins, the chicken breast weighs approximately 200 grams, so 300 to 350 calories.

Comment: Creatine is good.
I gained like 10 kg's with it.
So you can try that.
Just 3 grams a day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know whether or not you should add it is up to what your end goal is.  If your goal is to try and add muscle onto your frame then it might be an OK idea.  Else wise, I would need to know why you are eating so little and how much you currently weight/ your body fat %.  Over the years I've lifted/competed I haven't met a single person who doesn't question the legitimacy of most supplements.  Most of them, I feel, are scams to get more money in the companies pockets.  Whey Protein however is one of the "better" supplements as it gives you some extra protein if you feel you aren't getting enough.  That's why they're called supplements.  They are there to supplement your regular day to day diet.  Make sure you do your research on they protein company beforehand.  Most Walmart brands don't digest very well and in turn don't give nearly as much protein as they say they do.  I personally like MTS Whey.

TL;DR:  Most supplements are "Scams".  Whey Protein, Creatine Monohydrate, and Caffeine (Pre-Workout) is all most people need to achieve their goals.

EDIT: Must've missed the wanting to be toned part.  If you weight around 170 lbs and you're over 6ft tall (I'm American, I hate metric) then you definitely have plenty room to grow muscle wise.  Doing a slow bulk I feel would benefit you nicely to make sure you keep the extra body fat off.

To fully answer your question, YES I think that a protein shake would help your ability to build muscle.  I say this though because you seem to be doing high cardio work and eating such few calories.  Because of this, I believe if you added 100 calories worth of food a week until you start seeing you seem to be getting a little Watery or "Fluffy" then it would drastically improve your body composition.  Once you seem to start getting watery just cut the calories a little.

Also, you CAN retain your body composition by slowly upping your calories.  This will just increase your metabolism over the span of weeks slowly up until you reach a good staying point.  1900 calories for 170lbs is very little.